# Polynomials with purely imaginary coefficients?

Tags: polynomials

Finished a homework problem concerning polynomials with all real coefficients and why complex roots of p(z)=0 come in pairs. Curious is there is a similar situation for polynomials with all purely imaginary coefficients. I can't figure this one out.

Never used this site before. If this is incorrectly place, my apologies.

Comment: If all coefficients are purely imaginary, just factor *i*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every non-zero complex number $a$ and every polynomial $P$ the roots of $P$ and $aP$ are the same. Applying this with $a=i$ answers your question.